# Autocomplete include directories in c++

Tags: emacs, filenames, autocomplete

VisualStudio has some extension which checks the include directories and makes suggestions while typing. My current project uses a lot of included libraries, sometimes with rather long pathnames. Let's assume I can't do anything about that and I also cannot add the whole paths to my CMakeLists.txt.

**Question**: Is it possible to get emacs to suggest completions for include directories?

---

Example:

I am typing

```
 \#include "somelib/partoflib/subpart/FileName.h"
```

Is it possible for emacs to suggest

```
 \#include "somelib/partoflib/
```

once

```
 \#include "somelib/pa...
```

is unique?